# EditableTableModule : angular 4 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'EditableTableModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, npm, datatable

While trying to implement [EditableTableModule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-editable-table) I got this error log:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'EditableTableModule' declared by the
>   module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component
>   annotation.
>       at syntaxError (vendor.bundle.js:56199)
>       at vendor.bundle.js:69951
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata
>   (vendor.bundle.js:69933)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._loadModules
>   (vendor.bundle.js:81331)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.*compileModuleAndComponents
>   (vendor.bundle.js:81304)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync
>   (vendor.bundle.js:81233)
>       at PlatformRef*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.*bootstrapModuleWithZone
>   (vendor.bundle.js:86923)
>       at PlatformRef*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule
>   (vendor.bundle.js:86909)
>       at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (main.bundle.js:635) bundle.js:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: ng is not defined
>       at N (bundle.js:19)
>       at VueComponent.ready (bundle.js:15)
>       at VueComponent.LN.M._callHook (bundle.js:5)
>       at VueComponent.z (bundle.js:5)
>       at VueComponent.N (bundle.js:5)
>       at VueComponent.M.$emit (bundle.js:5)
>       at VueComponent.LN.M._callHook (bundle.js:5)
>       at z (bundle.js:5)
>       at VueComponent.M.$before (bundle.js:5)
>       at CN.transition (bundle.js:6) polyfills.bundle.js:5701 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geAdapter' of undefined
>       at WebSocket._ws.onopen [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYopen] (eval at M.exports (bundle.js:3), :97:46)
>       at WebSocket.wrapFn (polyfills.bundle.js:6671)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (polyfills.bundle.js:5930)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills.bundle.js:5697)
>       at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
>   [as invoke] (polyfills.bundle.js:6004)
>       at invokeTask (polyfills.bundle.js:7045)
>       at WebSocket.globalZoneAwareCallback (polyfills.bundle.js:7071)

Can anyone help me find the solution ?